# How to develop same jqgrid in multiple tabs?

Tags: jqgrid

My problem is , I have a datatable which displays Order details.

If i click on an order, a new tab will get opened and in that tab a jqgrid will be displayed with the detailed order information. Here i am using only one jqgrid, and dynamically loading data into jqgrid using "url" option.

And if I open another tab for another order, the jqgrid is not displaying. ie.Simultaneously in two tabs the same grid is not working.

Please suggest me, how can i achieve this..

Comment: Are you using jQuery UI tabs? Wouldn't you want to load a different grid into each tab? If not, perhaps tabs are the wrong UI element for your application?

Comment: @JustinEthier Actually i have to use the same grid, for this i   identified  two approaches. 1.Overriding grid id using  tab reference and  this  worked good. 2.Setting context ,or scope, for a tab and while defining  the  grid specifying this context as in $("#grid_id",ourscopeparameter).jqgrid(grid options); But in this approach, the jqgrid is not working. The second approach is working with other ids but not for jqgrid.

Comment: Can we specify the context or scope for jqgrid?, is there a way to do it?

Comment: Found a similar answer to this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12175130/tabs-in-jquery-for-loading-jqgrid
Hope it helps you.